# font awesome not found

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

I added the flutter dependency for font awesome, but as soon as I try importing the package, I get the error below.

```
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
font_awesomme_flutter: ^8.4.0
```

```
    import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
```

> error : Because bmi_calculator depends on font_awesomme_flutter any
>   which doesn't exist (could not find package font_awe somme_flutter at
>   https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed. pub get failed
>   (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...

flutter doctor returns no error.

Also, every time I run a command to troubleshoot this problem, I get this : <<

> Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...

I'm having to repeatedly stop dart from the task manager and delete the lock file from the flutter folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please correct the name in your dependencies

it's **font_awesome_flutter** you have written it as **font_awesomme_flutter**

as well as you should be careful with indentations

Comment: You're welcome, please consider marking the answer with tick mark so others can see it as well, for their ease

Answer (score 1):

Spacing importance is more in pubspec.yaml file. Check out how i bellow code i it should be.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.4.0
```